# Facing Error 1053 in case of windows service

Tags: c#

I made a windows service. My code is similar to:

```
onstart()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

I am trying to update my database every minute.
The service builds properly and installed properly, but when I start the service it gives error 1053.
I have tried alot to solve it but not get any solution.

Comment: How can that be your code? It is not syntactically correct. Please post the real thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you define `onStop`?

> The ServiceBase class calls the OnStop
>   method directly from the Service
>   command handler that is defined in the
>   ScDispatcherLoop of the Advapi32.dll
>   file. After 30 seconds, if the
>   ScDispatcherLoop thread is not ready
>   to receive a new service command from
>   the service control manager, Windows
>   Service Controller marks the service
>   as "time out." Therefore, you receive
>   this error message.
>   [-Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839174)

Comment: thanks for reply can you please give any idea to solve this problem

Comment: what do you do in your `onStop` method?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    //put debugger.launch the first statement of OnStart...and make sure you running in    debug mode
    Debugger.Launch();

    try
    {

      //your code
      . 
      .
      .
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //see what exception is coming
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to the console of the server (in the server room if you will) and start the Window Service. Remote in won't work.